# ssreflect inversion, I need two equations instead of one

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I have next definitions (code can be compiled):

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Set Asymmetric Patterns.

Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Inductive val : Set := VConst of nat | VPair of val & val.
Inductive type : Set := TNat | TPair of type & type.

Inductive tjudgments_val : val -> type -> Prop :=
| TJV_nat n :
    tjudgments_val (VConst n) TNat
| TJV_pair v1 t1 v2 t2 : 
    tjudgments_val v1 t1 ->
    tjudgments_val v2 t2 ->
    tjudgments_val (VPair v1 v2) (TPair t1 t2).
```

And I would like to prove the following lemma:

```
Lemma tjexp_pair v1 t1 v2 t2 (H : tjudgments_val (VPair v1 v2) (TPair t1 t2)) :
  tjudgments_val v1 t1 /\ tjudgments_val v2 t2.
Proof.
  case E: _ _ / H => // [v1' t1' v2' t2' jv1 jv2].
  (* case E: _ / H => // [v1' t1' v2' t2' jv1 jv2]. *)
```

- The `case E: _ _ / H => // [v1' t1' v2' t2' jv1 jv2].` leaves me with `E : VPair v1 v2 = VPair v1' v2'`.
- The `case E: _ / H => // [v1' t1' v2' t2TPair t1 t2 = TPair t1' t2'' jv1 jv2].` leaves me with `E : TPair t1 t2 = TPair t1' t2'`.

But it looks to me like I need both of them together. How to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [way](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/user-extensions/proof-schemes.html#coq:cmd.Derive-Inversion) of using `inversion`'s power with ssreflect tactics.

```
Derive Inversion tjudgments_val_inv with (forall v t, tjudgments_val v t).
```

You can use it with `elim/tjudgments_val_inv: H`.

The proof is straightforward after this.

Answer (score 1):

In such a case, you can use the very handy `inversion` tactic an enhancement of the `case` tactic, which automatically does the kind of work of indices you are manually trying to do. Here `inversion H` is almost enough to finish the proof.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As far as I understand, 'vanilla' tactics like inversion can be inconsistent with ssreflect tactics. Am I wrong?

Comment: I wouldn’t say that they are inconsistent: you can very well mix up ssreflect and vanilla tactics in the same development or proof without major risks. However, it is true that the "style" favored by ssreflect and the one naturally adopted when using vanilla tactics are often quite different, so mixing up both is in general not such a great idea, as it often makes for clumsy proof.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I faced problems when mixing vanilla and ssreflect tactics sometimes.. but yes, styles are different anyway, good point.